# ng-repeat and ng-if syntax for arrays within arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I have an array within an array and I'm having some issues with ng-repeats and ng-ifs.  My array looks something like this:

```
data.stage = [];
task_obj = {};

data.stage.push({
                workflow_stage: wf.getDisplayValue('name'),
                task: []
            });

task_obj.number = userTasks.getValue('number');
            task_obj.parent = userTasks.getValue('parent');
            task_obj.state = userTasks.getValue('state');
            task_obj.url = userTasks.getDisplayValue('url');
            task_obj.incompleteCounter = incompleteCounter;
            task_obj.icon = icon;
            task_obj.status = status;
            task_obj.style = style;
            task_obj.short_description = userTasks.getValue('short_description');
            task_obj.bundle_name = bundle.getValue('bundle_name');
            task_obj.workflow = bundle.getDisplayValue('workflow');
            task_obj.workflow_stage = bundle.getDisplayValue('workflow_stage');

for(var a=0; a < data.stage.length; a++){
                if(bundle.getDisplayValue('workflow_stage') == data.stage[a].workflow_stage) {
                    data.stage[a].task.push(task_obj);
                }
            }
        }
```

If I have an ng-repeat that looks like `ng-repeat="item in data.stage track by $index"`, how would I access the short_description for example?  Would it be like `{{item.task.short_description}}`?

Similarly, if I wanted to write an ng-if where bundle_name is "MyBundle", how would I write it?  I've tried `ng-if="item.task.bundle_name=='MyBundle'"`, but it obviously doesn't work.

Can anyone guide me on the correct syntax?

Comment: You need to use a `ng-repeat` for array `task` and then for every loop use this `item_task.short_description`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ng-repeat for task also

```
<div ng-repeat=ng-repeat="item in data.stage track by $index">
    <div ng-repeat=ng-repeat="task in item.task track by $index">
         <div ng-if="task.bundle_name == 'MyBundle' ">
             My bundle condition 
         </div>
         <span>{{task.short_description}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```